# Word for someone searching for reason to hate another

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that describes the following type of situation:

Person A already hates Person B.  Person A then subsequently searches for reasons to further hate and roast Person B.  These attempts may get progressively more and more ridiculous, but Person A continues the attempts.

What would you call this?

Comment: I would call it **obsession**.

Comment: Certainly an obsessive-type situation, but what type?

Comment: It would be hatemonger

Comment: Sounds like *confirmation bias* to me....https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is the activity of an "internet troll" but in real life. The word "detractor" comes to mind but seems mild, and the ever increasing nature of the scenario seems an important aspect of your question.

The best I could come up with is "hatred", "malevolence", "acrimony", or "antipathy", but perhaps preceded with "unglued", "escalating", "ongoing", "ever-increasing" or something similar. Possibly "unglued acrimony" would work.

Comment: Acrimony does seem to be the closest by far.  Is there a variation that would mean "acrimony driving into absurdity"?

Comment: Possibly "insane acrimony", "irrational acrimony, "unglued acrimony", "precipitous acrimony" or something similar?

Comment: Unglued acrimony would do it.  If you put that in the answer, I'll choose that.

Answer (score 1):

I would call them prejudiced or biased against the person. Both words carry the meaning of unfair dislike.

From the Oxford dictionary:

> [Prejudice](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prejudice): Preconceived opinion that is not based on reason or actual experience.
>
> [Bias](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bias): Inclination or prejudice for or against one person or group, especially in a way considered to be unfair

Comment: Hm, prejudice seems close.  But does it necessarily mean searching for reasons to hate a person?